# Ignorar se é maiúscula e minúscula na string

Tags: python, string

```
n1 = input('Qual é o seu bolo favorito?')

if n1 = 'Bolo de Chocolate':
   print('teste123')
```

Se o usuário escrever "Bolo de Chocolate" tudo em minusculo ou tudo em maiúsculo, vai acabar acontecendo de não entrar no `if` que eu criei, alguém sabe se tem alguma função que ignore se tiver em maiúsculo ou minúsculo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) para transformar tudo em minúsculo. Sempre que tiver uma dúvida se tem uma função para fazer alguma coisa, você pode procurar na documentação oficial sobre o tipo de dado que está trabalhando. Ficaria assim:

```
n1 = input('Qual é o seu bolo favorito?')
if n1.lower() == 'bolo de chocolate':
    print('teste123')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p4yuND). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/reyuevyi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/LowerNormalization.py).

Poderia usar o `upper()` também. E claro que não resolve todos os outros problemas da pessoa digitar diferente, o que é muito mais provável que dê algum problema.

Comment: seria bom colocar ambos os lados da verificação com lower() ou upper()

exemplo:
if n1.lower() == 'bolo de chocolate'.lower()

Comment: @le314u por que?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que comparar ambas as versões em minúsculo (ou maiúsculo). A função `.lower()` de uma string transforma todos os caracteres em suas versões lowercase:

```
n1 = input('Qual é o seu bolo favorito?')

if n1.lower() == 'bolo de chocolate':
   print('teste123')
```

Comment: seria bom colocar ambos os lados da verificação com lower() ou upper() exemplo: if n1.upper() == 'bolo de chocolate'.upper()

Answer (score -3):

Pra resolver de vez o seu problema, invés de dar ao usuário a possibilidade de escrever (uma vez que pode acontecer de digitar errado e neste caso nunca vai entrar no if) vc pode oferecer uma lista de respostas para ele selecionar uma delas. tipo usando o AutoCompleteEditText em seu layout no lugar do EditText.

Comment: bacana seu raciocínio de AutoCompleteEditText mas e se a pessoa não quiser que a resposta esteja explicita... suponhamos que você eteja elaborando um jogo de charadas